# AngularJS loaded and syntax check with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, load

I am trying to add a loading overlay to my site depending on if angularjs is loaded without any errors.

Currently I have the following small script that allows me to check if angularjs is getting loaded in:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function () {
        if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
         document.getElementById("page-loader-overlay").style.display = "block";
        } else {
         document.getElementById("page-loader-overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
    };
</script>
```

What I would also like to check, is making sure that the browser isn't giving any specific syntax errors due to a part of code that might not be read-able by a specific browser making the above check obsolete.

Is there a specific way to add a syntax check to this check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use sublime text3 and install plugin like jslint

Comment: That is not what I am looking for, I am looking for a way to trigger a specific action if the user's browser shows specific syntax errors.

Comment: than  add debug; in scripts top and add breakpoint in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can detect syntax errors using a global [onerror handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror), and check if the error is an instance of `SyntaxError`:

```
<script>
onerror = function(messageOrEvent, source, lineno, colno, error) {
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    console.log('Caught a syntax error: ', arguments);
  }
}
</script>
<script>
let f/4; // syntax error
</script>
```